# ON & OFF Android Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Im creating an app in which i do a task when i receive a call (detect RINGING state with a BROADCASTRECEIVER ).My question is that,can I register and unregister (literally;ON and OFF) his broadcastreceiver from an activity having 2 buttons;say one for ON and another for OFF?

Does it require the BROADCASTRECEIVER to be declared inside the activity?If I do so,can i register and unregister it,via the activity?

Comment: yes subru(sics) please post your code

Comment: see the editted code Mr.Ramz...

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: its not the answer Mr.Tom....but its abt the code written by me....thats y i didnt post it with the question before....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the way i would do it:

- I define a separate BroadcastReceiver and define it in android manifest rather than using it in your activity. Doing this allows my broadcast receiver to work independent of activity
- Write an activity with two buttons (On/Off) and save its action as a flag in shared preferences
- update the broadcastreceiver's onReceive method and check if a flag in preference is set to true then handle the intent, otherwise ignore it

Answer (score -1):

> //use to enable the broadcast receiver 
>   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
>                           PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

```
//use to disable the broadcast receiver
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

please try this subru